# Junction Tables: Changing many-to-many to one-to-many in Entity Framework model

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I've got a set of tables as below:

> **PositionShiftPattern**
>   PositionShiftPatternID
>   PositionID
>
> **EmployeePositionShiftPattern**
>   EmployeePositionShiftPatternID
>   EmployeePositionID
>
> **TemplateShiftPattern**
>   TemplateShiftPatternID
>
> **Week**
>   WeekID
>
> **PositionShiftPatternJunction**
>   PositionShiftPatternID
>   WeekID
>
> **EmployeePositionShiftPatternJunction**
>   EmployeePositionShiftPatternID
>   WeekID
>
> **TemplateShiftPatternJunction**
>   TemplateShiftPatternID
>   WeekID

So PositionShiftPattern, EmployeePositionShiftPattern and TemplateShiftPattern each have a junction to Week, with one-to-many relationships inbetween.

Obviously EF will map the relationships between PositionShiftPattern, EmployeePositionShiftPattern and TemplateShiftPattern and Week as many-to-many and create navigation properties from each table directly to Week.

Is it possible to then change the many-to-many relationships to one-to-many relationships (e.g. each Week should map to a single ShiftPattern)? I'm trying to achieve mutual exclusion (see diagram below) and want to avoid just adding PositionShiftPatternID, EmployeePositionShiftPatternID and TemplateShiftPatternID to Week. Should I be looking at another way of achieving mutual exclusion?

[image: Mutual Exclusion]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible. The relation must be the same as in the database. If you create one-to-many relation it will be considered as a new one and you will have to add those Ids to week. Also when looking at your model it doesn't make sense to introduce such relation. At the moment Shift can be related to many weeks and week can have many shifts. If you introduce one-to-many it will mean that each week instance can have only one shift.

Comment: @Gib: My answer is still valid. Your database is not modeled for mutual exclusion. You should start with your database schema because it don't make sense with your requirement and you will have to add those ids to week table to build one to many relation. You will also have to validate that only one id is filled.

Comment: OK, I'm gonna go with adding the fields to Week and removing the junctions. Thanks for answering Ladislav.